# Array of instance initialization in Typescript : Is "new MyClass" mandatory?

Tags: typescript

I declare a class (This is just a simple example. I do not use a type alias because the constructor is more complex, there are functions in the class, ... so I need a class)

```
class Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
        this.name= name;
        this.age= age;
  }
}
```

To init an array of instances, I use the following code :

```
persons: Array<Person> = [
        new Person("Joe",30),
        new Person("Jack",40)
]
```

I wonder if there is a mean to avoid to repeat many times `new Person`. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I would consider leaving the array initialization as-is. The reason is you would be trading text repetition (as opposed to logic repetition) for runtime complexity. I would be onboard if this was reducing the duplication of code/logic, but it doesn't appear to be in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is common, you can create a helper function that takes a class an the parameters of the constructor:

```
class Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}


function newMany<T, P extends any[]>(cls: new (...p: P) => T, ...p: Array<P>): Array<T> {
    return p.map(a => new cls(...a))
}

var persons: Array<Person> = newMany(Person,
    ["Joe", 30],
    ["Jack", 40]
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gWAFDQOjTAFt4AuaCAF0QEs0BzAbj0OjEYqIFcSAjJK3yFg6Goh7BqKRAApiZShIaMANBy6U0fQYgCUWNu0LUAFnQgA6RfGgBeIqXjCTpi9c53HX14QC+eIG4eHgAZjxo0nToRPAA7gCyYGgAngA8ACoasNDwAB7U8GgAJjApqQDaALoAfHKgENoJ0HJW7QAOlLCG9rXQ2dDtVl3QAIKIiGAZsLX6lBNTGZn9OCIEiPDUPIgYHVYkYB1yYA79aC2Nbe1g+vpBobgAbmCI0B1IqGhN45PT6QhkOh+o4LkkKnJAV81MYCJUAEQAKRQ8HhGgAzAAGaow9bQBGIsDAADWaOgABZsXh9MwgA)

I would consider using an interface though if your class only has data fields, this is the way things usually are done in typescript:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

var persons: Array<Person> = [
    { name: "Joe", age: 30 },
    { name: "Jack", age: 40 },
];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMqciHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzFnJzO3kCulAEbR2RAL7FiANzhRkAB0w4MdAIJQocAJ4AedFGwgAfMgC8yANocyeclV4AiAFJYIDgDRcedAMwAGZDF3a1JbCmo6Z0QAaw8vXgAWAKDiAF1WIA)

Comment: Thanks for answers. My class has not only datafield. That is why I use a class. Briefly, I am learning TS and of course at the beginning, I used a type alias as you did in the second part of your answer. But now, I added some checks in the constructor, some fields that are automatically generated (for example inscriptionDate), ... The solution with the helper function is exactly what I expected but I have not, yet, the skill required to write it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer was also an educational answer. I finally understand all the details of your function `newMany`. Many TS concepts are inside. If I may, can I edit your answer to add : Array<T> as return type ?

Comment: @Stef1611 Sure, I added the explicit annotation. I generally let the compiler infer where it can

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally clear what you are trying to achieve but if you are hardcoding the values (Joe, Jack etc), you can store them in an array and use `Array.map()` to map it with `Person` instances, as following:

```
const personList = [
    {name: 'Joe', age: 30},
    {name: 'Jack', age: 40}
]

persons: Array<Person> = personList.map((person) => new Person(person.name, person.age))
```

Hope this helps

---

And also you can reduce the class definition by adding access modifiers in the constructor:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {}
    //                  ^^^ this.name       ^^^ this.age
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Using an array of object to store hard coded datas and after mapping it to put it in another array of object is not natural for me. I come from the C and Arduino worlds and this kind of data duplication is, in my mind, a memory loss. I know it is very very small. Thanks for the trick of access modifiers. I am going to integrate them in the Titian's answer.